# Broadcasting Intent or starting Activity from separate java class: Null object reference error

Tags: java, android

Moved methods that broadcast intents or start activities (Launch Google Assistant, Volume Up/Down, pause audio) from Service to a separate java class in order to call them using invoke and a string as their name rather than using countless of if statements (the methods are triggered upon a button press from a bluetooth device).

I am getting a NullPointerException Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
method 'void 
android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a 
null object reference
10-19 16:53:25.277 8073-8133/com.example.android.zeno W/System.err:     
at 
android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:396)
```

The Java class extends the Service where the methods were previously located.

This is one of the methods (triggers Google Assistant) located in a separate class called ActionsPhonecontrol:

```
public class ActionsPhonecontrol extends BluetoothLeService {

boolean PCL_googleNow() {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    return true;
}
```

This is the method that invokes the other methods from the separate class:

```
void invokeAction(String method, String className) {
    broadcastUpdate(method);
    String mType = getPackageName() + "." + className;

    //trigger received sound
    soundPlay(R.raw.blip1, 500);

    try {
        Class mClass = Class.forName(mType);
        Method mMethod = mClass.getMethod(method);
        Object newClass = mClass.newInstance();
        String p = (String) mMethod.invoke(newClass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it shows the error?

Comment: You don't need to extend from your service. If you want just to put the methods in separated classes, just create an helper class with static methods and then you can pass the context as parameter. Also, drop that invokeAction method, you don't need this to invoke methods from your own application, just need a better project architecture. (assuming that you are using it to call PCL_googleNow

Comment: where is your send broadcast method? where is the call for this?

Comment: you're manually instantiating a service and manually calling one method. Of course, the service is not properly initialized, so among other things, its Context is Null (the error you're getting). Services must be started with "startService". What you might be after is to declare your methods elsewhere as STATIC, and call them without all the introspection mambo jambo.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will implement the helper class. Some more context: The user can change what actions (methods) are triggered with each button in settings. That's why I used the invokeAction method. The "method" string is loaded from SharedPreferences. I "startService" when the app connects to the bluetooth device. Is this sufficient?